# jQuery .remove() removes all my children from the container not just one

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im working on building out a full page transition using aJax calls. I want to remove content from the DOM when I load in a new page.  Some reason .remove() is removing all the children from the parent container even though Im adding a unique class or ID on it. I've tried several ways of targeting the element I want to remove but it keeps doing the same thing. remove() should only be removing one element, that is the element with the class name 'remove-from-dom' When I use addClass it targets the element correctly.

```
                    $(response).prependTo('.swap-content');

                    var slideWidth = $('.swap-content').width();
                    $('.ajax-load-in-remove').animate({
                        left: + slideWidth
                    }, 1000, function () {
                        $('.ajax-load-in-remove').css('left', '').removeClass('hide-me');
                        $('.ajax-load-in-remove').last().addClass('remove-from-dom');
                        $('.remove-from-dom').remove();

                    });
```

my container looks like this

```
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child">
        <div>
        <div class="child remove-from-dom">
       <div>
    </div>
```

.remove() should only be removing the last child in the container but its removing both children. I only have 2 children.  I have tried using IDs and have used .last-child and .last()

Comment: Running `.remove()` on class selector will remove all elements with the specific class. This is the correct behaviour.

Comment: You don't specify which one `.remove-from-dom` should be removed. You can add ID, or be more specific.

Comment: why you set a class and then remove it , you can remove that element for one like this : $('.ajax-load-in-remove').last().remove();

Comment: The reason I was adding a class then removing it because  $('.ajax-load-in-remove').last().remove();  wasn't working ether so I was trying something else

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that reproduces issue

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam there can only be one `last()` at any specific moment

Comment: oops wrong copying, sorry for that  
does adding `console.log( $('.remove-from-dom').length)` inside the `ainmate complete` funtion prints `1` or more than one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are doing the removing inside the callback when the animation ends.

But you are running the animation on many elements `$('.ajax-load-in-remove').animate`, so the callback is fired for each animation ending. And each callback is removing the currently last element.

You can use the `.promise` which resolves when all animations have completed.

```js
$('.ajax-load-in-remove')
  .animate({
    left: +slideWidth
  }, 1000)
  .promise()
  .then(function() {
    $('.ajax-load-in-remove').css('left', '').removeClass('hide-me');
    $('.ajax-load-in-remove').last().remove();
  });
```

Comment: Thank you! That was my issue. I thought I was loosing my mind.

Comment: @user3369825 added a solution as well

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the last one `.ajax-load-in-remove`, use

```
$('.ajax-load-in-remove').last().remove();
```

You don't need to add `remove-from-dom` class to this element, it was just a step more to make an action.

Comment: This still does the same behavior.

Comment: No, it removes just one element, not whole collection with the same class. The removed element it that one from line `$('.ajax-load-in-remove').last().addClass('remove-from-dom');` - I think it's the right element which you meant.

Comment: Yes I've already tried the exact code which was how I was doing it originally but it still is removing the child above it as well.  This is really strange.